# How to bring a JPanel to the front of the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have a project due tomorrow so I need help.
I'm making a clock I largely got help from others and I need to get a JButton to the front. I have the button as part of a JPanel

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Clock");  
        Color c=new Color(0,0,0);  
        Clock clock = new Clock();
        JPanel p=new JPanel();

        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        window.pack();


        window.setBackground(c);  
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
        Button buton =new Button("Stopwatch");

        p.add(buton);
        window.getContentPane().add(clock);  
        window.setVisible(true);
        clock.start(); 
}
g.setColor(Color.black);//Background color
        g.setFont(new Font("ComicSans", Font.BOLD, 20));  
        g.setColor(Color.white);//inner circle color
        g.fillOval(xcenter - 150, ycenter - 150, 300, 300);  

        LocalDateTime time =LocalDateTime.now();
        String strTime =time.toString().substring(14,19);
        String strHour =time.toString().substring(11,13);
        int hour =_12hrFormat(strHour);

        g.setColor(Color.black);//time color
        g.drawString(hour+":"+strTime ,141,300);  
        g.setColor(Color.black);//number color
        g.drawString("9", xcenter - 145, ycenter +10);  
        g.drawString("3", xcenter + 135, ycenter +10);  
        g.drawString("12", xcenter-10 , ycenter - 130); 
}
```

That is most of the code to do with visuals

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. Half of it is outside the method. It's referencing things you haven't included. It's certainly not a [mcve]. What does "bring a JPanel to the front of the JFrame" mean?

Comment: What are the lines starting with `g.` in the second code-half after closing _main_ block `}` ?  Maybe you can __post a screenshot__ and mark on it what you want where.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is definitely not completed. But let’s presume you draw your oval and other staff in **paintComponent**. Also you have to add your JPanel to Frame.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("some frame");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.setContentPane(panel);
```

Then you can add whatever you want on it.

And I hope your **g** is part of paintComponent.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just panicking because this is all due tomorrow